# Building Custom Mosaic Dataset Overviews in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mosaic-dataset

We'd like to resample our mosaic dataset using the `MAJORITY` option, but it it isn't given in the `Build Overviews` tool. Our plan is to generate the rasters manually using `Resample` and `Split` GP tools, and then register them with the mosaic dataset.

Once we've created the TIFFs that we're going to use as overviews, how do we register them as such within the mosaic dataset? How do we let ArcGIS know that these rasters should be used as overviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is relatively straightforward. Just add the custom overviews using `AddRastersToMosaicDataset_management`, then field calculate the `Category` field to `2`, which is a coded value for `Overview`.

The `MinPS` and `MaxPS` values in the mosaic dataset attribute table will also need to be adjusted for both primary and overview rasters so that the overviews display properly.